# Bootstrap navbar only working after resize with IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am helping a friend with the design of his homepage using bootstrap 3. Now the design is almost ready, but we have come across a strange behaviour of the navbar at the bottom of the page when accessing the page with IE9. As usual there are four sizes defined (large, medium, small, xtrasmall). If the page is loaded for the first time with IE9 in large or medium size, the navbar does not work. Only after re-sizing the window to at least small or xtrasmall the navbar works - even in large or medium.

With Chrome, FF or Safari, everything works fine.

Any idea, how we could fix the behaviour?
website:
www.theballroomshow.com

Bernhard

Comment: I always stack smallest to largest min-widths and largest to smallest max-widths because that's the order. Even though you have min-widths and max-widths in your media queries, try  min-width:1200px styles after all other styles and the others in min-width smallest to largest order first is css/stylesm.css, then the md.css, then lg.css the xs is a max-width, put that first . Also, you know that there's better ways to do responsive css than 4 files, you can put inside one css file, but do that later after this is fixed.

Comment: Basically, just reverse the order of your linked css files.

Comment: I reversed the order of the linked css-files. Unfortunately it does not make a change. Even worse, if I put the style.css at the end of the linked files, the language navigation at the top right appears at a wrong place. I have changed it on my test webseite [link](http://www.bernhard-malle.de/fileadmin/Ballroomshow/index.html)

Comment: No, you put the order of the media queries <link href="css/stylelg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/stylemd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/stylesm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/stylexs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> in reverse not the style.css

Comment: Hi Christina, thanks for again looking into it. I had changed the order on the following testsite:[testsite](http://www.bernhard-malle.de/fileadmin/Ballroomshow/index.html) as you suggested, but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to a sort of "IE9 z-index" bug. I found this:
http://icreatestuff.co.uk/blog/article/ie9-z-index-stacking-problem-or-something-stranger

and added a transparent 1x1 "fixer.png" to the navbar. Now it works immediately in IE9 without resizing.
Glad, that I am using Firefox most of the times.
:-)